# "Error: path must be a string", while building react app using browserify, babelify, gulp and watchify

Tags: build, reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I was trying to build implement Gulp, Browserify, Babelify, Watchify and React build process following this [tutorial](http://mikevalstar.com/post/fast-gulp-browserify-babelify-watchify-react-build/). Here is the full code,

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var streamify = require('gulp-streamify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var merge = require('utils-merge');
var duration = require('gulp-duration');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var path = {
  ENTRY_POINT: './js/App.js',
  DEST: './dist/',
  OUT: 'build.js',
  MINIFIED_OUT: 'build.min.js'
};

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  var args = merge(watchify.args, {
    debug:true
  });

  var bundler = browserify(path.ENTRY_POINT, args)
      .plugin(watchify, {ignoreWatch: ['**/node_modules/**', '**/libs/**', '**/plugins/**']})
      .transform(babelify, {preset: ['es2015', 'react']});

  bundle(bundler);

  bundler.on('update', function() {
    bundle(bundler)
  });
});

function bundle(bundler) {
  var bundleTimer = duration('Javascript bundle time');

  bundler
      .bundle()
      .on('error', mapError)
      .pipe(source(path.MINIFIED_OUT))
      .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./map'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST))
      .pipe(notify({
        message: 'Generated file: <%= file.relative %>'
      }))
      .pipe(bundleTimer)
      .pipe(livereload);
}

function mapError(err) {
  if (err.fileName) {
    gutil.log(chalk.red(err.name)
        + ': ' + chalk.yellow(err.fileName.replace(__dirname + '/js/', ''))
        + ': ' + 'Line ' + chalk.magenta(err.lineNumber)
        + ' & ' + 'Column ' + chalk.magenta(err.columnNumber || err.column)
        + ': ' + chalk.blue(err.description));
  } else {
    gutil.log(chalk.red(err.name)
        + ': '
        + chalk.yellow(err.message));
  }
}

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Demo App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Admin Module for Demo App",
  "main": "js/App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify -e ./js/App.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] -o ./dist/bundle.min.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-router": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-duration": "0.0.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-react": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-streamify": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "utils-merge": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      {
        "presets": [
          "es2015",
          "react"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "author": "Sagun Pandey"
}
```

Whenever I try to build my app with `npm run build` or `gulp watch` I get this error:

```
Error: path must be a string
```

This was working until I was using `reactify`. I would appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: Relates to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571362/browserify-fails-to-create-bundle-with-babelify-transform-typeerror-path-must

Comment: I found the issue. Actually, my entry point App.js had the extension name missing. I corrected it and now everything is working fine.