# Browserify --standalone with ES6 modules and multiple source files and exports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs, browserify

I am trying to use Gulp, Browserify, and Babelify to compile and transform multiple ES6 files into a single JavaScript library that can be shared with other developers.

I am trying to use multiple ES6 source files, each of which uses [ES6 modules using `export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). I want them all to be wrapped up into a single class/function like a 'namespace'.

It seems like [Browserify's --standalone option](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#browserifyfiles--opts) is designed to do this, but I can only get it to work when there is a single input file. When there are multiple source files with exports, I can't get them all to be included in the 'namespace' class, and I can't control which source file's exports ultimately gets picked to be in the 'namespace' class.

In this example, `a.js` and `b.js` are the source files, and I am expecting them to be bundled together in a 'namespace' class called `TestModule`.

**a.js**

```
export function fromA() {
    console.log('Hello from a.js');
}
```

**b.js**

```
export function fromB() {
    console.log('Hello from b.js');
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const browserify = require('browserify');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const log = require('gulplog');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

function minimalExample(done) {
    return browserify({
            entries: [
                './src/a.js',
                './src/b.js'
            ],
            standalone: 'TestModule' // output as a library under this namespace using a umd wrapper
        })
        .transform('babelify')
        .bundle()
            .on('error', log.error)
        .pipe(source('minimalExample.js'))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}

module.exports = {
    minimalExample
};
```

**What I want**

I want minimalExample.js to have an object named `TestModule` that has functions `fromA()` and `fromB()`, so that I can call both methods. I should be able to run either of these commands from the console:

```
TestModule.fromA()
TestModule.fromB()
```

**What is actually happening**

When I load minimalExample.js in a browser, open the console, and inspect the `TestModule` object, it exists, but it is missing the function from `a.js`. It only has the function from `b.js`:

[image: TestModule has only the fromB() function]

Am I missing a setting somewhere? Is there a way to get Browserify to include all the exports in the standalone 'namespace' class?

---

**Update 1**

Prompted by @Zydnar's discussion, I did the obvious thing and actually looked at the output file, minimalExample.js. I don't understand how the transforms are intended to work or what is going wrong yet; I'm still looking at that. But I do see both input files have been transformed and included in the output.

Here is the [actual output](https://pastebin.com/jJ7CwLD3), and the same thing but [pretty-printed by Chrome](https://pastebin.com/dGczgHjx).

Comment: I bet if you'll replace in entries `'./src/a.js',` with `'./src/b.js',` and vice versa, you'll have TestModule.fromA but not TestModule.fromB. I guess something after browserify replaces what actually should be appended.

Comment: @Zydnar Oddly that is not what happens. Swapping them around still gives me the output from b.js. I don't seem to be able to pick which one is included (ETA: short of commenting all but one out). I thought of that too, because for my actual use case I could work around it if I could choose which files is included, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: What do you need this line: `.pipe(source('minimalExample.js'))` for? And what is in this file? It looks like you override stream.

Comment: Nothing is in that file, that is the output file. Up until that point, the objects being chained are not Vinyl objects. Browserify outputs [a standard Node stream.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571362/browserify-fails-to-create-bundle-with-babelify-transform-typeerror-path-must) So they must be converted from a Node stream to a Vinyl source stream for the rest of the gulp pipeline to work.

Comment: @Zydnar This is interesting though; your question prompted me to do the obvious thing and examine the actual output in minimalExample.js. I still don't exactly understand what is going on, but I do see both of my source files transformed in the output. I'll post an update shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [help on the browserify project on Github](https://github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/1186#issuecomment-572118966), I have an answer for this. Renée Kooi pointed me in the right direction. They said:

> If you have multiple entry points, all of them are executed, but browserify doesn't merge modules, which could cause bad unexpected behaviour.

The solution is to have a single file that acts as an entry point for Browserify that exports everything you want exported. Use that single file as your input source file in the `entries` option. Browserify will walk your app's dependency tree and include the dependencies it requires. Anything exported by the entry point file will be included in the exported module as expected.

---

A complete example follows. `main.js` is the entry point file.

**a.js**

```
export function fromA() {
    console.log('Hello from a.js');
}
```

**b.js**

```
export function fromB() {
    console.log('Hello from b.js');
}
```

**main.js** (This one is new)

```
export * from './a.js';
export * from './b.js';
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const browserify = require('browserify');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const log = require('gulplog');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

function minimalExample(done) {
    return browserify({
            entries: [
                './src/main.js'  // THIS LINE HAS CHANGED FROM THE QUESTION
            ],
            standalone: 'TestModule'
        })
        .transform('babelify')
        .bundle()
            .on('error', log.error)
        .pipe(source('minimalExample.js'))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}

module.exports = {
    minimalExample
};
```

Now when you run the `minimalExample` task with gulp, the file generated will have both `TestModule.fromA()` and `TestModule.fromB()` functions.